# Performance in Static classes vs Immutable singleton-pattern objects managed by IoC container

Tags: java, c#, scala, static, singleton

I'm currently writing C# code and I wonder if using singleton-patter objects managed by the IoC container instead of static classes has any benefit beside loose coupling.

Assuming all fields and properties in the implementation are immutable.

Comment: How exactly is creating singletons answer to loose coupling? The fact that you're accessible to those object from anywhere in your code just creates implicitly coupled code.

Comment: You program against the interface of the class. and  bind the interface and the class with per-container lifetime in your IoC container?

Comment: Can't say that is has performance leaks, because IoC must run additional thread to manage all singletons (registers it), creates additional context to manage life cycle of it and so on and so on...So using static classes is probably one of the straightforward cases. BUT if you wanted to switch singletons by some application mode like "development" or "deployment", probably the IoC gives you better control of desirable objects at runtime and forces to use only what you intended to use.

Comment: "because IoC must run additional thread to manage all singletons (registers it)"? Is there one very specific IoC you are talking about... I don't see why one would do that.